# value undefined while decoding json with jquery

Tags: json, jquery

I know there are already many questions related to this topic, but I tried a lot of them but I am still unable to get the values.

I am using firbug and I am getting the right response as :-

```
[{"id":4,"comments":1,"likes":5,"books":3,"name":"steve"}]
```

But I am not able to display them on the page. When I try alert(data.id) I get undefined in the alert box. Here's my code :-

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                               alert(data.id);

                    }
                });
```

I tried

```
$.each(data, function (key, element) {
                            alert(key); 
                            alert(element); 
                        });
```

This shows key as 0 but element as [object Object] in alert box

Comment: You have an array, `console.log(data[0].id)`.

Comment: set up a fiddle for everyone to play with jsfiddle.net/pnYzq

Comment: and what if what the firebug is really showing is element itself? So maybe alert(element[0].id) would do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your response is an array.

Either do

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data[0].id);
}
```

or only return an object

```
{"id":4,"comments":1,"likes":5,"books":3,"name":"steve"}
```

or if you want to keep an array use the `each` as such

```
$.each(data, function (key, element) {
    alert(key); 
    alert(element.id); 
    alert(element.comments); 
    alert(element.likes);
    ... 
});
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you set a breakpoint before the alert?

Comment: u mean break; before alert(key) - it says "unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch"

Comment: This sure looks like the correct answer. Though it should be "element.likes" in the last statement.

Comment: No, I mean "setting a breakpoint" in your browser's debugger.

Comment: hey, the last part seems to work. Must have made a mistake before. I tried again. Its working